# Can I get the number of views for a question over time with the API?

Tags: support, api, views

I have this link that gives me Python questions for a particular week:

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions?fromdate=1519862400&todate=1522368000&order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&tagged=python

This shows the views per question. Is there an option to view date-wise view of question? E.g., question x raised on 2 Feb may have 2010 views, on third it has 1824 views and fourth it has 276 views as the views may be the next day.

Do they provide this option or am I asking too much?

Answer (score 3):

The site only records the total number of views, it doesn't record when they happened. There's just a counter that increments each time a question is viewed.